# Running multiple conditions on two dataframes using the merge function to create pairs

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements

I have two dataframes -

```
ID  Currency_a  Amount_a    Date_a
1   CAD         100         12-Jan
2   CAD         200         12-Feb
3   USD         200         15-Aug
4   USD         200         12-Jan
5   EUR         200         12-Feb
```

```
ID  Currency_b  Amount_b    Date_b
6   CAD         500         25-Jan
7   CAD         600         13-Feb
8   USD         200         15-Aug
9   USD         400         20-Jan
10  EUR         200         12-Feb
```

The task is to create a pair of `(ID,ID)` from the 2 respective data frames if -

The currencies are the same

`Amount_a + Amount_b > 600`

Time period between Date_a and Date_b is less than 10 days

So the output in this case should be

`(2,7), (4,9)`

I am using (but it doesnt seem work :( )-

```py
a.merge(b, on='Currency).query('Amount_a + Amount_b > 600' and 'abs((Date_a - Date_b).dt.days) > 10').filter(like='ID').values.tolist()
```

Comment: (4, 9) equals 600 not greater than 600.  Should that be `>= 600`?

Comment: What have you done to try to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
df1['Date_a'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Date_a'], format='%d-%b')
df2['Date_b'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Date_b'], format='%d-%b')

df_out = pd.merge_asof(df1.sort_values('Date_a'), 
              df2.sort_values('Date_b'), 
              left_on='Date_a', 
              right_on='Date_b', 
              left_by='Currency_a', 
              right_by='Currency_b', 
              tolerance=pd.Timedelta(days=10), 
              direction='nearest')

df_out.query('Amount_a+Amount_b >= 600')[['ID_x','ID_y']].apply(tuple, axis=1).tolist()
```

Output:

```
[(4.0, 9.0), (2.0, 7.0)]
```

Answer (score 0):

`dt.days` is not supported by `query`. So maybe this:

```
(df1.merge(df2, left_on='Currency_a', right_on='Currency_b')
    .assign(date_diff=lambda x: x.Date_a.sub(x.Date_b).dt.days.abs())
    .query('date_diff < 10 & Amount_a + Amount_b > 600')
    .filter(like='ID')
    .values
)
```

Comment: SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal